# Glassfish V3.0 weird deployment error when using primefaces components

Tags: java, deployment, jakarta-ee, glassfish, primefaces

Today i started using some new tools from primefaces into my JSF pages new to me. I notice that some of this tools for some reason do not allow me to deploy my project. and this is what i see:

[image]

And the console says this:

> SEVERE: Class [ Lorg/slf4j/Logger; ] not found. Error while loading [ class    managedbeans.UploadController ]
>   WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
>   SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load EJB module.  DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB  Check archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\jeeAplicationServer\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps\GarbageTheWeb
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load EJB module.  DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB  Check archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\jeeAplicationServer\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\eclipseApps\GarbageTheWeb
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

The component that i am tiying is the simple file upload from prime faces, it looks exacty as in this link: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf

Am i ussing the correct impor statement?

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://seam-framework.2283336.n4.nabble.com/glassfish-and-Seam-Faces-error-td3272490.html

For some reason it needs this 2 jar files in the classpath:

slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar

Sorry :)

Comment: Yes, the exception also tells that: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger`.